# MVC routing my GET request to the wrong action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I've got a URL routing issue in my application. I've tried to tackle the issue, but haven't really made any headway.

So, I'm making the following AJAX request client-side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: programState.getBaseUrl() + 'Playlist/GetPlaylistsByUserId',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        userId: user.get('id')
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("JSON data:", data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Here's the network:

[image]

Here's the server error:

[image]

Here's the Controller's methods for GET and GetPlaylistsByUserId:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(Guid id)
{
    Playlist playlist = PlaylistDao.GetById(id);

    return new JsonDataContractActionResult(playlist);
}

[HttpGet, ActionName("GetPlaylistsByUserId")]
public ActionResult GetPlaylistsByUserId(Guid userId)
{
    IList<Playlist> playlists = PlaylistDao.GetByUserId(userId);

    return new JsonDataContractActionResult(playlists);
}
```

and finally, here are my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "{controller}/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "post-Playlist",
    "{controller}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "create" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "get-Playlist",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "get" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "put-Playlist",
    "{controller}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "update" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("PUT") }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "delete-Playlist",
    "{controller}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "delete" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("DELETE") }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

As best as I can tell -- I am getting my URL routed to my 'Get' action, but I am intended it to be routed to the 'GetPlaylistsByUserId' action. I believe this to be happening because the server error states that it is looking for a paramater 'id' for method 'Get.'

I'm not sure why any of this would be happening, though, as I seem to quite clearly have my other action mapped...?

Comment: Try your original code but with a nullable Guid? as the parameter. See if it gets through to the correct Action handler and then check for userid.HasValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the route to the request - you're requesting an action name, which doesn't match the route. As it stands, your routing expects your ajax request to go to `.../Playlist/SomeGuid` as opposed to `Playlist/GetPlaylistsByUserId?userId=SomeGuid`.

If you want to route all requests to your `Playlist` controller to the GetPlaylistsByUserId action if no action is specified, the route you want is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "Playlist",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

Note the omission of userId - this is passed as a querystring and doesn't need to be included in your route. MVC will bind this automatically.

As it stands, however, you *are* requesting an action name, so the following route will pick this up:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "Playlist/{action}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

You could also use `{controller}/{action}` but I am guessing you don't want all controllers to default to an action called `GetPlaylistsByUserId`.

Comment: Hey, trying to follow your example.. hitting other routing issue. I'll let you know when I get stuck or have more to add.

Comment: I've accepted your solution for the key fact of pointing out that {controller/{action} is not the same action Playlist/{action}

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "{controller}/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

I'm not sure if this could be it, but is there any chance it's because you don't have `{action}` in your Url pattern?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "{controller}/{action}/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the Request url looks like

```
Playlist/GetPlaylistsByUserId?userid=51d77etc...
```

and your routing is set up as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "{controller}/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

They don't match.

For this route to be used, the url should look like:

```
Playlist?userid=51d77etc...
```

or your url should stay the same and the route mapping should be

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "{controller}/{action}/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation. I agree and have tried out your bottom bit of code. However, I am still receiving the same error. Interestingly enough, if I change GetPlaylistsByUserId to accept a string and make my userId paramater optional -- I get into the action OK. I still think it is getting confused with the other GET

Comment: Note my answer - you are passing `userId` as a querystring value, not a route value. Hence, it should not appear in your routing.

Comment: Yep I've tried that, too. I'm getting different errors currently -- it at least is routing to the proper action, but the server is initializing the route with a null GUID and it errors out.

Answer (score 1):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "{controller}/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

should be changed to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getPlaylistsByUserId",
    "{controller}/GetPlaylistsByUserId/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Playlist", action = "GetPlaylistsByUserId" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```